# Link to controller action in html

Tags: php, html, yii2, action

It is possible to create

> href="controller action"

with id of model?

I have this code and i want to use html href to actions of controller.

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
?>  

<div class="news">
    <div class="context-menu">

        <a href="#" title="" id="dropdownProfile" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><i class="icon-circle-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownProfile">
            <li><a href="#" title="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="header-news">
        <a href="#" title=""><img src="<?= Url::base(true) ?>/img/ania.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <p class="author"><?= $model->getUser($model->urUser_Id); ?></p>
        <p class="date"><?= $model->CreatedAt; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-news">
        <p><?= $model->Text; ?></p>
    </div>
    <?= $model->getStatus($model->cnNewsContentType_Id); ?> <br>

    <?php
    if ($model->getId($model->urUser_Id) == Yii::$app->user->identity->Id) {
        echo Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Edytuj'), ['update', 'id' => $model->Id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
        echo Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Usuń'), ['delete', 'id' => $model->Id], [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => Yii::t('app', 'Jesteś pewien, że chcesz usuńąć tego newsa?'),
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ]);
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

There is dropdown list in html where i want to paste link of actions of my controller.

```
<li><a href="#" title="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
```

There instead of # i want to use this action edit and delete it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
   <?php echo Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'yourItemLabel'), 
    Url::to(['/yourController/yourAction',
         'id' => $model->id]), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</li>;
```

or you can simply assign an url to your href

this sample is for a relative path

```
echo    '<a href="./index.php/myController/myActio/?id=1" 
            class="btn btn-success btn-block">mylinktext</a>';
```

Comment: whether it takes into account id appropriate model?

Comment: look at my code on bottom. I use code like you give me. I asked for something else. I want to know that is possible that i use html href as a link to my actions which i have on bottom of my code

Comment: Yes is possible but you must build a proper (absolute or relatve) url . i have update the asnwer .. i hope this is what you are looking for ..

Comment: can i do somethink to set this buttons one under one like in <li> list now one is on right of  second i want to list this